# Alloc - add as accessoryView - release: does it leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, uitableview

Does this leak memory? This code is executed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` outside the cell creation block (so each time the table cell is updated).

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
// ... configuration code
cell.accessoryView = myView;
[myView release];
```

Or in other words, will the `UITableViewCell` release the object in its `accessoryView` when a new object gets assigned to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the cell will release the accessory view and you do not have a leak in the example.

Answer (score 1):

The property `accessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell` is a `retain` type, in common with many view properties in the kit. Check the Apple documentation for `UITableViewCell` to convince yourself of this. Therefore there will be no leak in your example - the retain count has been correctly managed. You've also correctly released after setting the accessory view, on account of your `alloc` call.